# How can we use this.responseText in XMLHttpRequest's callback even though it was not defined in the function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, javascript-objects

I am reading a tutorial that has a code like this:

```
function handleSuccess () { 
console.log(this.responseText); //the HTML of something.com
}
const asyncRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
asyncRequestObject.open('GET', 'https://something.com');
asyncRequestObject.onload = handleSuccess;
asyncRequestObject.send();
```

I know that javascript will create a new scope inside any new function, but the handleSuccess callback function is using the term "this" to refer to the XMLHttpRequest and use its responseText property, how is that possible?

Comment: `this` isn’t part of a (non-arrow) function’s enclosing scope; it’s set by how the function is called. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Most, if not all, event listeners in javascript set the `this` of the callback to be the element that fired the event. Same goes for  click event listeners for example, where the `this` inside the callback will refer to the DOM element that fired the event

Comment: @Ry- Thank you very much. Is this a new feature? I am sure I read about scoping somewhere else where it was like I mentioned without any clarification on this

Comment: Nothing about the `this` here is a new feature, no. (Arrow functions are a new feature, but there aren’t any here; I just mentioned them because `this` works differently inside them.)

Comment: @Ry- I know about scoping in arrow functions but I never encountered anything like this before, I am still a beginner in javascript though. Thanks